# Regex exclude &#

Tags: regex

How to determine that string doesn't contain both symbols &# together using regular expression ?

Comment: Did you try *anything*?

Comment: What flavor of regex?

Comment: What do you mean by “together”? In exactly that order? Try negative lookaheads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
/^(?!.*&#)(.*)/m
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/n9zkpO/1)

Comment: Or (s)he can use a `!Contains("&#")`

Comment: Assuming that is in the user's language...

Comment: Same goes for the negative lookahead ;)